# Redis expire a key but don't delete?

Tags: caching, redis

In redis, is there a way to mark a key as expired but don't actually drop it from the database? A use case for this would be to let a client know that they need to pull in fresh data from a producer of that data, but if the producer is unreachable, still have the stale data available in the cache. This would make it simpler as one would not have to leverage a separate database / redis cache for stale data and data that is meant to expire to trigger an update to the cache.

Answer (score 0):

There's no builtin way to do that.

In order to achieve the goal, you have to do the expire work by yourself. You can save the data into a hash with last modification time:

```
hset key data value time last-modification-time
```

When you retrieve the data, you can compare the last-modification-time and current time to check if the data is stale.

When you update the value, also update the last-modification time with current time.

In order to make it easy to use, and atomic, wrap these logic into a Lua script.